# database migration from gcp postgresql to external database

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to migrate databases from GCP postgresql to an external database? and what is the best way to do it? Sorry in advance if I'm dumb. This is my first time doing something like this.

re-read the documentation but did not understand if I can do this without stopping the master database.

Comment: Have you tried pg_dump?

Comment: Have you tried [`DMS continuous migration](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/migration-types#continuous-migration) And [pg_dump](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/import-export-dmp#export_data_from) and also can share what is your destination database?

Comment: I would like to understand if streaming replication is possible, that is, I want to replicate the databases, and then transfer the replica to the master mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Google Cloud` `Postgresql` supports [Logical replication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication#logical_replication) which has Change data capture(CDC) functionality. Basically, `PostgreSQL` logical replication can be described as a streaming representation of the `Write-Ahead Log (WAL)`. The  `Write-Ahead Log` maintains a record of all the data changes on the `PostgreSQL` database.

As stated in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/you-can-now-use-cdc-from-cloudsql-for-postgresql)

> Logical replication enables the mirroring of database changes between two Postgres instances in a storage-agnostic fashion. Logical replication provides flexibility both in terms of what data can be replicated between instances and what versions those instances can be running.
>
> Logical decoding enables the capture of all changes to tables within a database in different formats, such as JSON or plaintext, to name a few. Once captured, they can be consumed by a streaming protocol or a SQL interface.

Hence, you can get near real-time data in your replica. You may have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication) as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I have another question, if I create a read replica on the master in gcp, can I make a logical replica from it to a new server, will this not affect the master, if new tables are added to the master, they will also be replicated along the chain to the replication end point (to the second replication server)?

Comment: @INikitenkov As per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication#:~:text=Cloud%20SQL%20read%20replica%20instances%20can%27t%20act%20as%20publishers%20for%20logical%20replication%20because%20PostgreSQL%20doesn%27t%20support%20logical%20decoding%20in%20read%20replicas.%20However%2C%20the%20flags%20are%20enabled%20on%20the%20read%20replica%20instance%20to%20ensure%20that%20it%20can%20serve%20as%20a%20replacement%20for%20the%20primary%20if%20and%20when%20it%20is%20promoted.)

Comment: `Cloud SQL` `read replica` instances can't act as publishers for logical replication because `PostgreSQL` doesn't support logical decoding in read replicas. Also it will not capture changes when new table created as it listens to changes in data from a SQL level, in terms of INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. Reference: [Set up logical replication and decoding](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication#:~:text=SQL%20level%2C%20in%20terms%20of%20INSERTs%2C%20UPDATEs%2C%20and%20DELETEs)